# Extract the content of the image from which the Windows workstations are installed?

Tags: windows, active-directory, disk-image, image

I am just developer who tries to debug one nasty error that happens only on the workstations that are built/installed from some corporate image of the Windows workstation.

I have no idea what "the image file" means and I have no access to it. My question is - is such image file something like Docker file which have just few lines that specify 'grab this system and install here', 'grab that program and install there'? Or can Windows image be extracted to the txt file that contains just those few lines?

My hope is that I can convince my coporate client to extract the image file into such simple script, delete the sensitive (corporation-specific) lines from this file and give it to me, so, I can rebuild the Windows image that is as close as possible the the client's computers and then I can recreate client machine on my local computers.

Is this possible?

The corporation/client uses Active Directory extensively, this can help or prohibit my intetions...

Comment: It's a WIM file. There are editors for it. I'm sure they can provided you with something, even if it's a vanilla VM that only has the initial WIM deployed to it.

Answer (score 3):

A Windows installation image can be *very* complex (integrated software, updates, drivers, options, policies, ...). Extracting the contents to a *short* description is more a deep analytic process than a simple use of some tool.

Instead, that image has been created by someone and there must be some documentation. I'd seriously ask for that documentation (sans confidential items).